# How to preload several images & progress bar in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, image-preloader

Given an array with the urls of several images to preload, I want to loop each image and, when each of them have been loaded, upload a Bootstrap's progress bar I'm showing in the screen while the images are loaded.

I've tried to loop that array in my Controller, using the .onload() method on each iteration to do this, but I only get the progress bar updated from 0% to 100%; I can't see each update step (0%...5%..25%... and so on).

This the relevant part of code I have:

**HTML + AngularJS**

```
    <div id="node-002" class="container-fluid node full-height animated fadeIn" ng-controller="node-002">
      <div class="row full-height">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 full-height">
          <p class="text-center text-loading">Loading {{progress}}%</p>
          <div id="progress-bar" class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{progress}}%">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
    var files = [
      '../assets/img/image-1.jpg', 
      '../assets/img/image-2.jpg',
      '../assets/img/image-3.jpg',
      '../assets/img/image-4.jpg',
      '../assets/img/image-5.jpg',
      '../assets/img/image-6.jpg',
      '../assets/img/image-7.jpg',
    ];

    app.controller('node-002', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$location', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $location) {
      $scope.progress  = 0;
      var filesLoaded  = 0;
      var filesToLoad  = files;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesToLoad.length; i++) {
        var file = document.createElement('img');
        file.src = filesToLoad[i];
        file.style.display = 'hidden';
        file.onload = function() {
          filesLoaded  ++;
          if (filesLoaded  === filesToLoad.length) {
            console.log('Files already loaded');
            $scope.progress = 100;
            // Do some stuff when all files are loaded...
          }
          else {
            console.log((100 * filesLoaded / filesToLoad.length) + '% loaded');
            $scope.progress = 100 * (filesLoaded / filesToLoad.length);
            $scope.$apply(); // Is it mandatory?
          }
        }
        document.getElementById('hidden-data').appendChild(file);
      }
    }]);
```

What's the best way to perform this with AngularJS?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var filesToLoad  = files;`, where is the value of `files` variable?

Comment: Is the array of images to loop.